# Kerberos TGT renewal

Tags: authentication, kerberos

My understanding when renewing a TGT is that the new key is encrypted using the users password (or derivation of) so that they can decrypt it. But this means that the password must be stored in memory in order to use the new TGT.

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding wrong? Could the new TGT key be encrypted using the old TGT key?
2. If the password is stored in memory (so the user is not prompted again) why create a renewable TGT and not just get a new TGT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to correct your understanding of this.  Kerberos works by embedding secret keys into tickets of which there are two types, the TGT and the service ticket (ST).  Actual passwords are not stored in memory, nor placed into the tickets.  The encryption mechanism uses a derivation of the password plus a few additional items to prevent man in the middle and replay attacks.

1. New TGTs are not encrypted using the the old TGT key.  This is because part of the encryption utilizes the timestamp, which of course always changes.  So the old TGT is invalidated once it's time has expired, or the user requests a new one.  Moreover, TGTs are neither encrypted with the user's password or simply a derivation of it.  TGTs are encrypted with a timestamp and the KDC's master key, the latter of which which only the KDC knows.  The user cannot decrypt a TGT.  But by possessing it, the user proves knowledge he is who he says is, because when he first requests a TGT, he has already proven his own identity by sending an authenticator which is basically a hash of his password, a timestamp, and a few other items (such as IP address).
2. Passwords are never stored in memory and TGTs are renewable by default.  Only if the account for which the TGT has been issued is about to expire, or has been disabled, would the user of the account fail to be able to obtain a new TGT.  It is important to realize that part of the seamless single sign-on experience means TGTs are renewable by default.  Though the TGT is "renewed", it is in actuality a whole new TGT. The renewable flag just means that getting a new TGT is OK for that user. If you look at a network trace of this, you'll see that it is a new ticket. Finally, the only entity which can confirm/verify the value of this hash other than the user is the KDC.

As an FYI let me also suggest editing your post and adding the 'authentication' tag to give this a wider audience.

[image: How Kerberos works] 
[Diagram pictured above taken courtesy of computerworld.com](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2596424/networking/kerberos.html)

References: 
[Kerberos: An Authentication Service for Computer Networks](http://gost.isi.edu/publications/kerberos-neuman-tso.html)
[Kerberos Authentication Protocol](http://www.zeroshell.org/kerberos/Kerberos-operation/)

Comment: Thanks. That clears up a lot. Is there a new session key created when the TGT is renewed?

Comment: Yes ->  The session keys used for ticket-granting tickets (TGTs) and service tickets are short-lived and used only as long as that session or service ticket is valid.  Per:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772815%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396